# Year Long Raspberry Pi Timelapse

Tags: power, ups, poe

I am making a year long Raspberry Pi time lapse, I have a script that takes a picture every day but if there is power cut, the Pi turns off, and the script is stopped so I need the Pi on 24/7—any ideas?

BTW I am using PoE to power the Pi because I have it at the end of my garden.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider a powerbank like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012ZNMUL6) to deal with power interruptions, provided they are no longer than a few hours. This power bank is also a wifi router, though you might be able to find one that isn't. Most important feature is the fact that it can be recharged by plugging it in to an outlet - so you can insert the powerbank into an electrical outlet, and it will power your rPi directly from the outlet when there is power, and from the built-in battery when there's none. Just note that this is an indoor item, so you would need to build/buy an enclosure for the unit to keep it safe.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since your setup incorporates a POE switch to power the Pi, you need to guarantee the availability of that ***switch***, which will in turn guarantee the availability of the Pi. The link below is for a smallish form-factor model UPS for £65, which wont break the bank and ensure the Pi and the POE switch stay up:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000GL19BW/?coliid=I1JSKBMYXZYJFN&colid=2MOD8MYCCDUC5&psc=1&ref_=lv_ov_lig_dp_it

As a bonus, the extra sockets on the UPS allow you to additionally guarantee your Internet availability too. HTH with your project-

[image]